# Streaming a programatically created video to youtube using node and ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, youtube, rtmp

I've been trying to Livestream a programmatically created image to youtube using node. I've had very limited success using FFmpeg. While I have managed to create and save an image thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073876/node-js-buffer-data-to-ffmpeg) insightful thread, I have yet to make the code work for streaming to an RTMP server.

```js
const cp = require('child_process'),
    destination = 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/[redacted]', //stream token redacted
    proc = cp.spawn('./ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe', [
        '-f', 'rawvideo',
        '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
        '-s', '426x240',
        '-i', '-', //allow us to insert a buffer through stdin
        '-f', 'flv',
        destination
    ]);

proc.stderr.pipe(process.stdout);

(function loop() {
    setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); //run loop at 30 fps
    const data = Array.from({length: 426 * 240 * 4}, () => ~~(Math.random() * 0xff)); //create array with random data
    proc.stdin.write(Buffer.from(data)); //convert array to buffer and send it to ffmpeg
})();
```

When running this code no errors appear and everything appears to be working, however, YouTube reports that no data is being received. Does anybody know what is going wrong here?

**Update:** This is really counter-intuitive but adding a slash to the destination like this `'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/[redacted]/'` causes ffmpeg to throw a generic `I/O error`. This is really weird to me. Apologies if the answer to this is obvious, I'm really inexperienced with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is specifically a `ffmpeg` issue, so the node and javascript stuff is an unnecessary complication (unless `ffmpeg` isn't even executing). It's best to get the `ffmpeg` command working in a command-line interface before adding it to any code.

- YouTube requires an audio stream, so add `-re -f lavfi -i anullsrc` input option to generate silent audio.
- Output must be YUV 4:2:0 for live streaming, so add `-vf format=yuv420p` output option.
- It is also recommended to add `-g`, `-b:v`, `-maxrate`, and `-bufsize` output options when streaming ([examples](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites)).
- Set the encoders with `-c:v libx264 -c:a aac` output options to make sure it doesn't automatically choose the crappy, old encoder named flv1 which is the default for flv muxer (`-f flv`).